Reference request: $X$ is a Radon space iff it's Borel isomorphic to a universally measurable subset of $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$
According to the site Encyclopedia of Mathematics, we have the following result: if $X$ is a topological space such its Borel $\sigma$-algebra is $\mathfrak{B}(X)$ countably generated, then $X$ is a Radon space iff it's Borel isomorphic to a universally measurable subset of $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$. However, the site doesn't provide any reference. That's why I ask: where can I find a proof of this result?
